# woocommerce product dependency: variations that cannot be bought alone

Tags: php, woocommerce

Is there a way to set a specific product variation so it cant be bought without having another product in cart?

Example: 
I have a shop with 10 products and each with the variations "70g", "1kg" and "2kg". Now if you have "70g" variations in cart without another variation with higher value, a notice should appear and the checkout button should be disabled.

So I am looking for a way to prevent buying only variations of "70g" as those variations alone are not making profit.

I found this code to make minimum order value for cart and show a notice but I dont know how to adjust this for variations and disable buttons: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/minimum-order-amount/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for single products by giving them a specific category. It then shows a notice when cart has products out of that category only and denies checkout:

```
/** Renders a notice and prevents checkout if the cart only contains products in a specific category */
function sv_wc_prevent_checkout_for_category() {
    //  If the cart is empty, then let's hit the ejector seat
    if (WC()->cart->is_empty()) {
        return;
    }   
    // set the slug of the category for which we disallow checkout
    $category = '70g';
    // get the product category
    $product_cat = get_term_by( 'slug', $category, 'product_cat' );
    // sanity check to prevent fatals if the term doesn't exist
    if ( is_wp_error( $product_cat ) ) {
        return;
    }
    $category_name = '<a href="' . get_term_link( $category, 'product_cat' ) . '">' . $product_cat->name . '</a>';
    // check if this category is the only thing in the cart
    if ( sv_wc_is_category_alone_in_cart( $category ) ) {
        // render a notice to explain why checkout is blocked
        wc_add_notice( sprintf( 'Du hast ausschließlich 70g-Probierpakete in deinem Warenkorb. Aus wirtschaftlichen Gründen können wir diese nur in Kombination mit anderen Produkten anbieten. Bitte füge daher weitere Produkte zu deiner Bestellung hinzu.', $category_name ), 'error' );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'sv_wc_prevent_checkout_for_category' );
/**Checks if a cart contains exclusively products in a given category*/
function sv_wc_is_category_alone_in_cart( $category ) {   
    // check each cart item for our category
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {    
        // if a product is not in our category, bail out since we know the category is not alone
        if ( ! has_term( $category, 'product_cat', $cart_item['data']->id ) ) {
            return false;
        }
    }   
    // if we're here, all items in the cart are in our category
    return true;
}
```